# Squat Rack Pull Up Bar Attachment

Tags: weightlifting, exercise, muscle

I have a squat rack at home. Are there Pull Up Bar attachments for Squat racks? I know Dip Bar attachments exist.

1. Currently looking for a Full width pullup bar attachment. (bar extends fully from left to right). And length has to be adjustable so it can fit at different width gym squat racks.
2. Or I can also use the Barbell on the squat rack (however, prefer a U-Hook if one exists) vs the current J-Hook. So the barbell will not move/or slide.

**Dip Bar Attachment**

[image]

**J Hook Attachment**, looking for more squat U hook so bar bell does not slide
[image]

Note I prefer not to use the bar at the very top of squat rack structure, its too high and hard grip.

Comment: Just to be clear, the question is "does there exist...?", which is fine. But keep in mind that **purchase recommendations are specifically off-topic here**, so the question and any possible answer should avoid talking about specific brands. I just wanted to throw that in there so we don't need to close it or remove answers.

Comment: agreed, no brands, just name or type of equipment category @Alec

Comment: It's called a squat rack pull up bar attachment and they exist.

Comment: hi @DaveNewton I have looked on amazon and google, for that keyword, didn't see it "squat rack pull up bar attachment " for one that is adjustable width

Comment: @mattsmith5 Do you regularly change the width of your squat rack? There won’t be “internal” adjustable bars (because it doesn’t make a lot of sense); and most racks will have cross-bars for stability already. I’m having a little trouble picturing what exactly you’re looking for.

Comment: Hi @DaveNewton yeah I go to multiple gyms with different squat racks per question above, do you have picture of squat rack pullup attachment? Thanks

Comment: You're planning on taking something to attach to gym equipment? I'd be a little surprised if many were ok with that for liability reasons, or that that many gyms don't have some mechanism for doing pullups. It'd make more sense for *you* to provide a picture of how you'd want this to work--the only thing I can picture is the kind that goes inside a doorway with "nested" pipes for adjustment, with standard rack mounting flanges. I doubt that exists, but you could probably get a metal worker to build one for you.

Comment: yeah, the gym owners don't have an issue, I asked them, probably something portable like the dip bar attachment above @DaveNewton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An "adjustable pull-up bar" is the closest thing that you'll find that meets your needs. However, they come in a few variations and no one variation is going to do everything you want as mentioned in your question.

The first variety are the pull-up bars designed for doorways. This is where you might find something that is adjustable in width but they fixed in height (i.e. doorway height) and are not compatible with squat racks.

The second variety are designed for squat racks. Unfortunately, they are fixed in width and designed to be variable in height (e.g. pin into the rack holes for adjusting to athlete height). Since pull-up bars for racks are generally designed by the same manufacturer that made the rack, you'd want to shop in-brand. I've used the barbell in j-cups method before for Australian pull-ups and it works well. Never tried for normal pullups though.

---

Now, combining this question with your last question, the easiest way to make a pull-up bar "lower" might be to raise yourself. If you have boxes available to stand on you can likely get into a better starting position.